# Disable Past Dates in Metronic Template datetimepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, metronic

I'm using Metronic Template in my Laravel project.
Here I wanted to disable past dates in datetime picker plugin.
I have searched some blogs and most answers were to use `minDate:0` property.
But it seems this doesn't work in Metronic template.
Please help me if you have experience in such case.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control m-input" readonly="" name="followup_deadline" placeholder="Select date &amp; time" id="datePicker">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <i class="la la-calendar-check-o glyphicon-th"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And javascript/jquery code is here

```
$("#datePicker").datetimepicker({
            todayHighlight: !0,
            autoclose: !0,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00"
        });
```

Other details needed?
Looking forward your kind answer.

Comment: I'm using Metronic version 5.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved it using this format

Javascript

```js
   let todayDate = new Date().getDate();
   let endD = new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate));
   $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
      startDate : endD,
      weekStart: 7,
      todayBtn:  1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
   });
```

As you can see I have created a Date object and assigned it to `startDate` this then will disable all date behind the current date (even the time).

Html

```html
<div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    <input type="text" size="16" id="datee" class="form-control" name="date_needed" required>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn default date-set" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```